# neo4j: return top 10people with most mutual friends, and some more complicated queries

Tags: neo4j

My graph database contains of Users who are friends with each other. (User)-write->(text), (text)-contains->(tag).

Now I want to return the following queries:

1. Return top 10 users who has the most mutual friend with user X. I
   already done this query: This group of 10 users has the name Y

   > ```
   > MATCH (user:User)-[:FOLLOWS]->(mf)<-[:FOLLOWS]-(other)
   >
   > WHERE user.username = '@majorlyprofound'
   >
   > WITH other,count(DISTINCT mf) AS mutualFriends
   >
   > ORDER BY mutualFriends DESC
   >
   > LIMIT 10
   >
   > RETURN other
   > ```
2. Return the top 10 users who is friend with group Y, but not
   friend with X. "friend with group Y" means that user has as many
   friends in group Y as possible (max is 10).
3. Return the top 10 users who is friend with group Y, but not
   friend with X. And has texts with the same tag as X. Sort by the the
   number of times X has used a tag, and the number of times a user has
   used that same tag.

I hope query 3 is understandable, sorry about by bad English.
Thank you so much for all your help.

Comment: better try framing the queries yourself and post them here for correction and advice..

Comment: Please try it yourself, also use the cypher refcard at http://neo4j.org/resources/cypher (hint path patterns) You also might want to look into the neo4j online training at http://neo4j.org/learn/online_course